# Check if a string has a certain length and contains certain letters

Tags: c#

So I want to check that a string has all these attributes:

- Five characters long, and
- The first character is one of:

  - O, or
  - S, or
  - J, or
  - C, and
- The last four characters are digits.

This is my code:

```
Console.Write("IDnumber : ");
IDnumber= Console.ReadLine();
IDnumberLength = IDnumber.Length;
if (MemberNumber.Length == 5  && 
    char.IsLetter(IDnumber[0]) &&  <-- I know how to validate any letter but not certain letter
    char.IsDigit(IDnumber[1]) && 
    char.IsDigit(IDnumber[2]) &&
    char.IsDigit(IDnumber[3]) &&
    char.IsDigit(IDnumber[4]))
```

Comment: Sounds like the regular expression `[OSJC][0-9]{4}` would fit. Alternatively, your code plus `new char[] { 'O', 'S', 'J', 'C' }.Contains(IDnumber[0])`.

Comment: just keep in mind that the `char.Is` methods also check for Unicode characters http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm, so `IDnumber[1] >= '0' && IDnumber[1] <= '9'` might be preferred

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Regex` like this:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[OSJC][0-9]{4}$");

Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("J1234"));
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("J124"));
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("X1234"));
```

That would give you:

```
True
False
False
```

In your code you could use it like this:

```
Console.Write("IDnumber : ");
IDnumber = Console.ReadLine();
if (Regex.IsMatch(IDnumber, "^[OSJC][0-9]{4}$"))
{
    // Success
}
else
{
    // Failed
}
```

Comment: I'd add anchors for the front and back. This regex also matches 1O1234x.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a regular-expressions:

```
Boolean isValid =
    value.Length == 5 &&
    ( value[0] == 'O' || value[0] == 'S' || value[0] == 'J' || value[0] == 'C' ) &&
    Char.IsDigit( value[1] ) &&
    Char.IsDigit( value[2] ) &&
    Char.IsDigit( value[3] ) &&
    Char.IsDigit( value[4] );
```